# GridView in Android doesn't correctly display all their items

Tags: android, image, gridview

I'm trying to implement a `Custom GridView` with 57 items. But only the first five images are displayed correctly, the rest are repeated to scroll down. And to scroll up images are disoriented.

What I have to do to get the 57 images display correctly? Thank you

**Main.java**

```
public static int [] imagenesIngredientes = {
    R.drawable.rodilla_elige_ing_1, 
    R.drawable.ingre_1,
    R.drawable.ingre_2,
    R.drawable.ingre_3,
    R.drawable.rodilla_elige_ing_2, 
    R.drawable.ingre_4,
    R.drawable.ingre_5,
    R.drawable.ingre_6,
    R.drawable.ingre_7,
    R.drawable.ingre_8
    ...};

    gridViewFotos.setNumColumns(2);
    gridViewFotos.setHorizontalSpacing(10);
    gridViewFotos.setVerticalSpacing(10);

    GridViewImageAdapter adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(this, imagenesIngredientes);
    gridViewFotos.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Adapter.java**

```
private Activity context;
private int[] imagenes;

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity context, int[] imagenes) {

    super();

    this.context = context; 
    this.imagenes = imagenes;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    final RecordHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);
        holder = new RecordHolder();

        holder.imageItem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.participar_gridview_imagen);
        holder.imageItem.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Utils.anchoPantalla(context) / 2, Utils.anchoPantalla(context) / 2);
        holder.imageItem.setLayoutParams(params);

        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    return view;
} 

private class RecordHolder {
    ImageView imageItem;
}

public int getCount() {
    return imagenes.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/participar_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:listSelector="#FFFFFFFF" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/participar_gridview_imagen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your image binding code out of if else condition, as shown below

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final RecordHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);
            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.participar_gridview_imagen);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Utils.anchoPantalla(context) / 2, Utils.anchoPantalla(context) / 2);
            holder.imageItem.setLayoutParams(params);

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) view.getTag();
        }

            holder.imageItem.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: @user4152 Great.. dont forget to accept the answer for future reference for others